# Invalid Operation Exception was unhandled - can't update 2 things at once

Tags: mysql, vb.net, xampp

This form I made allows the user to change their username, password and/or security passphrase, and it connects and updates on XAMPP database. I have tried looking online, but I am very new to VB and nothing really makes sense.

The problem is I can change any one of them, but if I try change the other after I changed one I get the error: 
InvalidOperationException was unhandled
Connection must be valid and open

The error comes here:  **reader = objcommand.ExecuteReader**

**This is my code:**

`Imports MySql.Data
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class frmAccountSettings

```
Private Sub frmAccountSettings_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    objconnection.Open()
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand = New MySqlCommand
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.Connection = objconnection
    objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "Select * FROM Login"
End Sub

Private Sub btnBack_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBack.Click
    frmMainMenu.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub btnChangeUsername_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChangeUsername.Click
    Dim password1, newusername As String
    password1 = InputBox("What is the current password?")
    sqlstring = "SELECT password FROM Login WHERE Password = '" &
password1 & "'"
    objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
    reader = objcommand.ExecuteReader

    If reader.Read Then
        reader.Close()
        newusername = InputBox("Enter a new username")
        sqlstring = "UPDATE `Login` SET `username` =  '" & newusername &
"'  WHERE `Login`.`password` = '" & password1 & "'"
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlstring
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        objdataset = New DataSet
        objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset, "Login")

        objconnection.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect Username. Please make sure your credentials are correct and try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Authentication Failed")
        reader.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnChangePassword_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChangePassword.Click
    Dim oldpassword, newpassword1 As String
    oldpassword = InputBox("What is the current password?")
    sqlstring = "SELECT password FROM Login WHERE Password = '" &
oldpassword & "'"
    objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
    reader = objcommand.ExecuteReader

    If reader.Read Then
        reader.Close()
        newpassword1 = InputBox("Enter a new password")
        sqlstring = "UPDATE `Login` SET `password` =  '" & newpassword1 &
"'  WHERE `Login`.`password` = '" & oldpassword & "'"
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlstring
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        objdataset = New DataSet
        objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset, "Login")

        objconnection.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect Password. Please make sure your credentials are correct and try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Authentication Failed")
        reader.Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnChangeSecurity_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChangeSecurity.Click
    Dim password2, newsecurity As String
    password2 = InputBox("What is the current password?")
    sqlstring = "SELECT password FROM Login WHERE Password = '" &
password2 & "'"
    objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
    reader = objcommand.ExecuteReader

    If reader.Read Then
        reader.Close()
        newsecurity = InputBox("Enter a new security passphrase")
        sqlstring = "UPDATE `Login` SET `security` =  '" & newsecurity &
"'  WHERE `Login`.`password` = '" & password2 & "'"
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sqlstring
        objdataadapter.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text

        objdataset = New DataSet
        objdataadapter.Fill(objdataset, "Login")

        objconnection.Close()

    Else
        MsgBox("Incorrect Password. Please make sure your credentials are correct and try again.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Authentication Failed")
        reader.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class
`

Comment: What happen if more than one user have the same password?

Comment: There will only be 1 user ever in my system. Does this affect the code?

Comment: Well, of course this is a game changing situation. However, do not use the adapter to execute this kind of changes, work directly with the MySqlCommand

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but I am very new to VB/MySQL and only using notes my Teacher has given. Could you please direct me to what I need to change in my code?

Comment: I have updated my answer below using directly a command to change the username. from there you could apply the same tecnique to the other events in your code.

Comment: What happens is that I update the password, then when I try changing the username after updating the password, it asks me for the current username, and after I press OK, it gives me the same error?

Comment: The connection object is opened ad the Load event and then closed somewhere in your code. This is not a good design. A good design requires that when you open the connection you should close it immediately, when you need it again you need to reopen it and close when done. I will update my answer again

Comment: I declared this in my module?

    `'Procedure which checks whether or not the current connection is open and opens it, if it is closed.
    Public Sub connection_checker()
        If objconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            Try
                objconnection.Open()
            Catch ex As MySqlException
                MsgBox("Error connecting to database")
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that there are a couple of errors in your code. The most serious one is a logic flaw.
You can't be sure that two users choose always different passwords. You need to make sure that your datatable `Login` has a `primary key` on the `username` field  and use that field in your queries to uniquely identify the records to be changed. Also, changing a username used as primary key is not an easy task. You need to check if the new user name is not already taken by another user. And if your application is used in a shared environment you need to account also for concurrent changes (two user that decide to change their username to the same new name)

Also, the `SelectCommand` of the adapter is not the appropriate method to execute database updates. But, there is no need at all to involve the adapter for these operations, you could do everything with a `MySqlCommand`.

There is another security problem with storing passwords in clear text in a datatable. You should never do that, instead you should apply a hashing function to your password before storing it in the table.

However, limiting my answer to the current problem and excluding the concurrency issue, I would change your code in this way (of course `username` **should be** the primary key) ....

```
Dim password1, newusername, oldusername As String
oldusername = InputBox("Type the current username")
password1 = InputBox("What is the current password?")
newusername = InputBox("Enter a new username")

' identify the current user ... '
sqlstring = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Login` WHERE `username` =  @uname AND `password` = @pwd"
objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", oldusername)
objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", password1)
Dim result  = objcommand.ExecuteScalar
if result IsNot Nothing AndAlso Convert.ToInt32(result) > 0 Then

    ' we have good credentials, but the new user name should be unique '
    sqlstring = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Login` WHERE `username` =  @uname"
    objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", newusername)
    Dim result  = objcommand.ExecuteScalar
    if result Is Nothing OrElse Convert.ToInt32(result) = 0 Then
        ' we could change the username of the current user '
        sqlstring = "UPDATE `Login` SET `username` =  @newame WHERE `username` = @oldname"
        objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
        objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newame", newusername)
        objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@oldname", oldusername)
        objcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Username already taken, choose a different one")
    End If
Else
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials given")
End If
```

In this way you use the combination of user and password to uniquely identify your user in the database and change the exact record involved.

In the same way you ask for the username and password when you want to change the password field and update the field only if the username and password match.

**EDIT** According to your comment above, if there is only one user in the database then you could execute directly the change without any complex checking. (But this is really a case that could not be assumed to be generally common)

```
    sqlstring = "UPDATE `Login` SET `username` =  @newame WHERE `password` = @pwd"
    objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newame", newusername)
    objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", password1)
    objcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Another problem is the connection object. It is a global object opened at the Form_Load event and then is kept hanging around your code but in some places you close it and when you try to execute another database operation you forget to reopen in. It is a good practice to NOT have a global object for the connection, instead build one when required, use it and then destroy it

For example

```
Private Sub btnChangeSecurity_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnChangeSecurity.Click
    Using objconnection = new MySqlConnection(....connectionstring goes here ....)
        objconnection.Open()
        Dim sqlstring = "UPDATE `Login` SET `username` =  @newame WHERE `password` = @pwd"
        objcommand = New MySqlCommand(sqlstring, objconnection)
        objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newame", newusername)
        objcommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", password1)
        objcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

If you put your database access code inside a using statement like above, you create the connection object, open it, use it and when done, the End Using statement will close and destroy the connection.